# IIS Connection Pool Monitoring

Tags: iis, connection, monitoring, pool

I am trying to monitor the IIS connection Pool information. Basically, I want to know the number of connections available, Connections used, Un-released connections, waiting for Connections etc. Is there a tool that help me do this?

I am using ADO.NET and Managed Oracle Data Access Driver.

Comment: Windows Performance counters.

Comment: For some reason, i am not getting any entries for my application. I am using Oracle Managed Data Access.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor the Number of Connection Pools currently active and other information using the Windows Performance monitor.